# When number of marker or marker size increases, Custom Markers doesn't render completely in React Native IOS

Tags: android, ios, react-native, google-maps, react-native-maps

#### What I'm trying to do?

I am trying to render custom marker in Android and iOS using **react-native-maps** library, where the number of markers can range between 16-900.

---

#### Where am I stuck?

When the number of marker increases(>60) or the marker size is increased, some markers are not rendering completely in iOS. However, if user clicks on that area, marker gets rendered and is visible now.

This works fine in Android though, so my assumption is that there is some rendering issue with iOS.

---

#### What issue looks like?

[image]

---

**Markers format:**

```
markers = {
  ["key": 0, "latitude": 34.123, "longitude": 134.123],
  ["key": 1, "latitude": 35.123, "longitude": 135.123],
  ["key": 2, "latitude": 36.123, "longitude": 136.123],
  [],
  []
}
```

---

**Sample code:**

Note: Markers are fetched via an API and saved in state

```
import React from 'react';
import MapView, {PROVIDER_GOOGLE} from 'react-native-maps';

class CustomMap extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      markers: [],
      region: {
        latitude: 34.334653,
        longitude: 134.365288,
        latitudeDelta: 0.45,
        longitudeDelta: 0.45,
      },
    };
   }

   render() {
     const {
       region,
       markers,
     } = this.state;

     return (

      <View style={{flex:1}}>
        <MapView
          provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
          style={styles.map}
          initialRegion={region}
          region={region}
          ref={ref => (this.map = ref)}>
          {markers &&
            markers.map((marker, index) => (
              <CustomMarker
                marker={marker}
                key={index}
              />
            ))}
          </MapView>
      </View>
    );
   }
  }
 }
```

**Below is the CustomMarker class**

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {Marker} from 'react-native-maps';

const CustomMarker = ({marker}) => {
  const [tracksViewChanges, setTracksViewChanges] = useState(true);

  return (
    <Marker
      key={marker.key}
      coordinate={marker}
    >
      <Image fadeDuration={0} source={getIcon(marker)} />;
    </Marker>
  );
};

const getIcon = marker => {
  switch (marker?.id) {
    case a:
      return require('Assets/Images/img1/a.png');
    case b:
      return require('Assets/Images/img2/b.png');
    case c:
      return require('Assets/Images/img3/c.png');
    default:
  }
};
```

---

I tried following things:-

1. Tried using icon and image prop of Marker component of react-native-maps library but the issue was same after the number of markers increased from 700.
2. Used svg image instead of Image from react-native library.
3. When used default marker the markers rendered properly in ios as well as android.
4. Used ref in Marker Component to set TrackViewChange to false. [Reference](https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/issues/3384)

Comment: There is probably a limit to prevent all the markers on the map causing lag spikes. Do you need to render all markers at once / are they all visible on the screen at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Rendering all markers directly onto the map using a `.map()` function is probably not the best way to show your markers. I'm pretty sure your markers are not rendering properly to prevent rendering/performance issues.

A better solution might be to 'merge' multiple markers together if the positions are close to each other, depending on the zoom level. You might have seen other apps combine multiple markers into one when you zoom out to prevent hundreds of markers cluttering your view.

I searched a bit and there was already an issue posted in the `react-native-maps` repo about this. See: [Marker Clustering #2992](https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/issues/2992)

In the comments, a library is linked to provide this 'merging' capability. It hasn't really been updated in a while, but with 9.000 download/week as of writing this it seems like this library still works properly. I'd recommend giving it a try and see if your issue persist.

[react-native-map-clustering](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-map-clustering)

Taking a look at the source code, it doesn't look very complex. So with a bit of tuning you could probaly patch it to fit your exact needs.